# Spring WebFlow issue when using map to render form select

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dictionary, spring-webflow

I created this small web flow which is kind of working. I am rendering a form select with a map. The select is rendered but I can't assign the AccountType object to the form modelattribute object (Account). Also, Web Flow has a strange behavior because when clicking in any button it re-render the page (triggers on-render flow event) instead of the assigned method. It even does not throw an error when a transition is not properly defined. However, If I don't use a map the flow works without any problem. I also tried with a List, and got the same issue.
So I don't know if I can't do that or it is an webflow issue, but I would like to use map and trigger the setAccountType method in Account class to set mapped AccountType.

Thanks for you help,

**Account class**

```
package com.impera.bank.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

public class Account implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6364376664252103663L;
  private int accountID;
  private AccountType accountType;
  private Customer customer;
  private String description;
  private AccountStatus accountStatus;
  private BigDecimal balance;
  private BigDecimal maintenanceFee;
  private BigDecimal monthlyInterest;
  private BigDecimal annualInterest;
  private Date deletedDate;

  public Account(){}

  public int getAccountID() {
    return accountID;
  }

  public void setAccountID(int accountID) {
    this.accountID = accountID;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public BigDecimal getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public void setBalance(BigDecimal balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public BigDecimal getMaintenanceFee() {
    return maintenanceFee;
  }

  public void setMaintenanceFee(BigDecimal maintenanceFee) {
    this.maintenanceFee = maintenanceFee;
  }

  public BigDecimal getMonthlyInterest() {
    return monthlyInterest;
  }

  public void setMontlyInterest(BigDecimal monthlyInterest) {
    this.monthlyInterest = monthlyInterest;
  }

  public BigDecimal getAnnualInterest() {
    return annualInterest;
  }

  public void setAnnualInterest(BigDecimal annualInterest) {
    this.annualInterest = annualInterest;
  }

  public Date getDeletedDate() {
    return deletedDate;
  }

  public void setDeletedDate(Date deletedDate) {
    this.deletedDate = deletedDate;
  }

  public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
  }

  public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
  }

  public AccountStatus getAccountStatus() {
    return accountStatus;
  }

  public void setAccountStatus(AccountStatus accountStatus) {
    this.accountStatus = accountStatus;
  }

  public AccountType getAccountType() {
    return accountType;
  }

  public void setAccountType(AccountType accountType) {
    this.accountType = accountType;
  }
}
```

**AccountType class**

```
package com.impera.bank.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class AccountType implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -3857276389106113682L;
  private int accountTypeID;
  private String description;

  public AccountType(){}

  public int getAccountTypeID() {
    return accountTypeID;
  }

  public void setAccountTypeID(int accountTypeID) {
    this.accountTypeID = accountTypeID;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

**Flow Definition**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <on-start>
        <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.initializeCustomer()" result="flowScope.customer"/>
    </on-start>

    <!-- Setup Web Flow here -->
    <view-state id="customerform" model="customer">
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" />
         <transition on="confirm" to="confirmation" >
            <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.submitOrder(flowScope.customer)" />
        </transition>
        <transition on="next" to="addaccountform">
            <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.initializeAccountList()" result="flowScope.accountList"/>
            <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.initializeAccountTypeList()" result="flowScope.accountTypeList" />
        </transition>
    </view-state>

     <view-state id="addaccountform" model="viewScope.account">
        <on-render>
            <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.createAccount(flowScope.customer)" result="viewScope.account"/>
        </on-render>
        <transition on="previous" to="customerform" />
        <transition on="next" to="review" />
        <transition on="add" to="addaccountform">                   
            <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.addAccount(flowScope.accountList, viewScope.account)"/>
        </transition>
        <transition on="clear" to="addaccountform">
            <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.clearAccountList()"/>
        </transition>
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancel" />
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="review" model="customer">
        <transition on="previous" to="addaccountform" />
        <transition on="next" to="confirmation" >
            <evaluate expression="createCustomerController.submitr()" />
        </transition>
        <transition on="cancel" to="cancelOrder" />
    </view-state>

     <end-state id="confirmation"  view="confirmation"/>

    <end-state id="cancel"  view="cancel"/>

</flow>
```

**addaccountform.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>

<tiles:insertDefinition name="defaultTemplate"> 
    <tiles:putAttribute name="title"><spring:message code="addaccount.title.label" /></tiles:putAttribute>
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body"> 
        <div class="body">
            <div class="container">
                <h1><spring:message code="addaccount.header.label" /></h1>
                <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="account" action="${flowExecutionUrl}" class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><spring:message code="addaccount.form.label" /></legend>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <form:label class="col-md-3 control-lable" path="accountType"><spring:message code="addaccount.accounttype.label" /></form:label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <form:select path="accountType" items="${accountTypeList}" class="form-control input-sm"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="_eventId_add">
                                    <spring:message code="addaccount.action.addaccount" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="_eventId_previous">
                                    <spring:message code="addaccount.action.cancel" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="_eventId_confirm">
                                    <spring:message code="addaccount.action.submit" />
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="_eventId_next">
                                    <spring:message code="addaccount.action.next" />
                                </button>
                            </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </fieldset>  
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

**CreateCustomerController class**

```
package com.impera.bank.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.binding.message.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.binding.message.MessageContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.webflow.action.EventFactorySupport;
import org.springframework.webflow.execution.Event;
import com.impera.bank.model.Account;
import com.impera.bank.model.AccountType;
import com.impera.bank.model.Customer;
import com.impera.bank.service.CustomerService;
import com.impera.bank.util.ApplicationContextUtils;
import com.impera.bank.util.Utility;


@Controller
public class CreateCustomerController extends Utility {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1224258557397946554L;
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CreateCustomerController.class);
  private Customer customer;
  private List<Account> accountList;
  @Autowired
  private CustomerService customerService;

  public Customer initializeCustomer() {
    this.customer = new Customer();

    return customer;
  }

  public List<Account> initializeAccountList() {
    logger.debug("Creating account list");
    if (accountList == null) {
      accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
    }
    return accountList;
  }

  // This is the map that renders the select thing
  public Map<AccountType, String> initializeAccountTypeList() {
    Map<AccountType, String> accountTypeList = new HashMap<AccountType, String>();
    logger.debug("Creating account type list");
    AccountType at = new AccountType();
    at.setAccountTypeID(1);
    at.setDescription("Debit Account");
    accountTypeList.put(at, at.getDescription());

    at = new AccountType();
    at.setAccountTypeID(2);
    at.setDescription("Credit Account");
    accountTypeList.put(at, at.getDescription());

    at = new AccountType();
    at.setAccountTypeID(3);
    at.setDescription("Savings Account");
    accountTypeList.put(at, at.getDescription());

    logger.debug("Accountr list: " + accountTypeList.size());
    return accountTypeList;
  }

  public Account createAccount(Customer customer) {
    logger.debug("Creating Account ");
    Account account = new Account();
    account.setCustomer(customer);
    // account.setAccountType(new AccountType());
    return account;
  }

  public void clearAccountList() {
    logger.debug("Clear Account list");
    if (accountList != null)
      accountList.clear();
  }

  public void addAccount(List<Account> accountList, Account account) {
    logger.debug("Add Account: " + account);
    accountList.add(account);
  }

  public Event validateCustomer(Customer customer, MessageContext messageContext) {
    System.out.println(ApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext());
    if (isNullOrEmptyString(customer.getFirstName())) {
      MessageBuilder errorMessageBuilder = new MessageBuilder().error();
      errorMessageBuilder.source("firstName");
      errorMessageBuilder.code("createcustomer.firstname.required");
      messageContext.addMessage(errorMessageBuilder.build());
      return new EventFactorySupport().error(this);
    }
    return new EventFactorySupport().success(this);
  }

  public void submit(Customer customer) {
    logger.debug(customer);
    customerService.addCustomer(customer);
    logger.debug(customerService.getAllCustomers());
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe I need PropertyEditorSupport

Comment: So finally I created a custom converter and solve the problem